# Paralell planes intersect sphere, possible to find radius of one circle knowing distance between planes, radius, elevation?

Tags: circles, spheres

*Haven't had to converse in math-ese in a while, so please forgive my clumsy attempts to properly use terminology!*

I've got a sphere of unknown radius, intersected by two parallel planes, creating circles A and B

I know radius of A

I know the length of a line drawn perpendicularly from origin of Circle A and through origin of Circle B to the sphere "shell"

Radius of A is larger than radius of B (i.e. above line does NOT go through origin of sphere)

I know the distance between the planes that create Circle A and Circle B, again measured perpendicularly.

**Is it possible to find the radius of Circle B?**

*My specific numbers are a Circle A radius of 16.5, distance from outside of sphere to A is 9.4, and distance between A and B is 7.*

Answer (score 0):

$y = \sqrt{r^2 - x^2}$ (circle equation)

$r - 9.4 = \sqrt{r^2 - 16.5^2}$

$r^2 - 18.8r + 9.4^2 = r^2 - 16.5^2$

$18.8r = 16.5^2 + 9.4^2$

$r = 19.1814$ (the radius of the sphere)

$r - 16.4 = \sqrt{19.1814^2 - x^2}$

$2.7814^2 = 19.1814^2 - x^2$

$x = 18.9787$ (the radius of circle B)